# How can values in my dataframe be NaN and floats at same time

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run PCA from sklearn and i keep getting `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')`. It is surprising me since i used `df.dropna()` and `len(df)` went from 4096
 to 1566 after using `drop.na()`.

I have tried many things like reseting index, making explicit copy etc., but nothing worked. Example below will demonstrate a minimal example of what seems weird behavior to me.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([[0.11, 0.22],[1.11, 1.22]], columns=['s1', 's2'])
```

when i do

```
df_test[df_test.isna()]
```

i get:

```
  s1  s2
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
```

and when:

```
df_test[~df_test.isna()]
```

i get:

```
   s1    s2
0  0.11  0.22
1  1.11  1.22
```

what i expect from

```
df_test[df_test.isna()]
```

is:

```
s1  s2
```

with no rows. How can values in my cells be a valid float64 and NaN at same time, it is rather confusing...

UDPATE: Turns out NaNs were not the problem when running PCA, but in fact 2 infinity values crawled into my data and i didn't spot it in my 4096 x 15 dataframe until i realized NaNs were handled correctly all along. Thanks to all that replied!

Comment: you should be using `.any()` or `.all()` depending on your requirements: try `df_test.loc[:,~df_test.isna().any()]` and `df_test.loc[:,df_test.isna().any()]`

Comment: @anky_91 `df_test.loc[:,df_test.isna().any()]'  masks columns rather then rows.

Comment: are you looking for something like this `df_test.isna().any(axis=1)`

Comment: @codeprimate123 `axis=1` masks rows, really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Isn't `df_test[df_test.isna()].dropna()` what you expect?

Comment: several methods mentioned here seem to give a dataframe without any NaNs however when i try to use it for PCA i allways get the same error mentioned in the beginning of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `df_test.isna()`, it creates a boolean mask.

```
>>> df_test.isna()
      s1     s2
0  False  False
1  False  False
```

Now, when you do a filter using this mask, it'll return a `NaN`.

```
>>> df_test[df_test.isna()]
   s1  s2
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
```

If you don't want the `NaN` then just drop them.

> The parameter `how` determines if row or column is removed from DataFrame, when we have at least one NA or all NA.
>
> ‘any’ : If any NA values are present, drop that row or column.
>
> ‘all’ : If all values are NA, drop that row or column.

```
>>> df_test[df_test.isna()].dropna(how='all') # Depends on the situation
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [s1, s2]
Index: []
```

Comment: this returns no rows, but i expect to get rows, since they don't contain and NaN values

Comment: You said you expect no rows in the question.

Comment: I will accept this answer since it is the only one and it is correct. It didn't solve my problem as the problem wasn't in NaNs, but that is questions problem, not the answers.

Comment: yes I did, and your solution did make remove them, however my question was bugged from the start (see update in the main body)